# git push heroku and errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to push my rails application to heroku when I use git push heroku I got this error also my app in heroku not change at all.
I use rails 3.27

cannot load such file -- uglifier
  (in /Users/ehsanvalizadeh/Documents/cafemajale/cafemajale/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`block in require'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:31:in `registered_js_compressor'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/bootstrap.rb:18:in`block in run'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:80:in `call'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:80:in`compressor'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in `compress'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:265:in`block in js_compressor='
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `call'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in`evaluate'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:177:in`block in evaluate'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in`evaluate'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26:in `initialize'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in`new'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `build_asset'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in`block in build_asset'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in`build_asset'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in`find_asset'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:23:in `block in compile'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:212:in`block in each_logical_path'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in`each'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each_entry'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:198:in`block in each_file'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in`each_file'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:210:in `each_logical_path'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in`compile'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in`block (3 levels) in '
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9...]
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in`ruby_rake_task'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/Users/ehsanvalizadeh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in`block (2 levels) in '
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Can you run the app locally? Do you have therubyracer gem or equivalent installed?

Answer (score 1):

Put this line or change the existing in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'uglifier', :group => :production
```